# How can I prove that this sequence is correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

$$ \sum_{i=0}^n a_{i}\left(\begin{array}{c}k+n\\k+i\end{array}\right) = 1, \;\;\;\;\;\;\; n > 0, 1< k \leq n $$

and $$a_{i} = (-1)^i\left(\begin{array}{c}k+i-1\\ i\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide context for the problem?

Comment: @RobinCarlier prove that $a_{i}$ is the second equation.

Comment: Consider the Maclaurin series of $\frac{1}{(1-x)^a}$ and the inverse $(1-x)^a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Week seek to evaluate

$$\sum_{q=0}^n (-1)^q {k+q-1\choose q} {k+n\choose k+q}.$$

This is

$$\sum_{q=0}^n (-1)^q {k+q-1\choose q} {k+n\choose n-q}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^n (-1)^q {k+q-1\choose q}
[z^{n-q}] (1+z)^{k+n}
\\ = [z^n] (1+z)^{k+n} \sum_{q=0}^n (-1)^q {k+q-1\choose q}
z^q.$$

The coefficient extractor $[z^n]$ combined with the factor $z^q$
enforces the range (no contribution when $q\gt n$) and we find

$$[z^n] (1+z)^{k+n} \sum_{q\ge 0} (-1)^q {k+q-1\choose q} z^q
\\ = [z^n] (1+z)^{k+n} \frac{1}{(1+z)^k}
\\ = [z^n] (1+z)^n = 1.$$

Comment: I am really sorry but i can't understand what does   $[z^n]$ mean.

Comment: This is a coefficient extractor for [formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Extracting_coefficients).